# What are "Maps" and "Structs" in IAM policies data types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

From here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_datatypes.html

> This section lists the data types that are supported when you specify
> values in JSON policies. The policy language doesn't support all types
> for each policy element; for information about each element, see the
> preceding sections.
>
> - Strings
> - Numbers (Ints and Floats)
> - Boolean
> - Null
> - Lists
> - Maps
> - Structs (which are just nested Maps)

**Question:** What are *Maps* and *Structs* and where can I read more about them in AWS documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the page says - but wrongly links and poorly explains - those are all simply Json data types and are described in more detail in the rfc, eg https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-4 ("objects" or maps) and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-5 ("arrays" or lists).

All that page is really saying is that various json data types are used in various places within an IAM Policy.  You need to follow the details of the spec to see where those types might be used.  But wherever they're used, they're defined by the json types.

```
{
   "object": { "a set of": "key-value pairs" },
   "list": [ "an ordered list of", "values" ]
}
```